# Cannot find control with name: '[object Object]'

Tags: angular

```
<form nz-form (ngSubmit)="handleCreate()" [formGroup]="form">

  <nz-form-item *ngIf="errors && errors.length > 0" class="alert alert-error">
    <nz-form-label *ngFor="let error of errors">• {{ error }}</nz-form-label>
  </nz-form-item>

  <nz-form-item *ngIf="!(errors && errors.length) && warnings && warnings.length > 0" class="alert alert-warning">
    <nz-form-label *ngFor="let warning of warnings">{{ warning }}</nz-form-label>
  </nz-form-item>

  <nz-form-item>This action will create a task:</nz-form-item>
  <nz-form-item>
    <nz-form-item nz-row>
      <nz-form-label nz-col nzSpan="6">
        definition
      </nz-form-label>
      <div nz-col nzSpan="18">
        <app-stream-dsl>{{ dsl }}</app-stream-dsl>
      </div>
    </nz-form-item>
    <nz-form-item nz-row>
      <nz-form-label nz-col nzSpan="6" nzRequired [nzFor]="name">
        name
      </nz-form-label>
      <nz-form-control nz-col nzSpan="18" [nzValidateStatus]="form.controls.taskName.errors" nzHasFeedback>
        <input nz-input class="form-control input-sm"
               [id]="name"
               [name]="name" [formControlName]="taskName"
               type="text" placeholder="<Task Name>"/>
        <nz-form-explain *ngIf="form.controls.taskName.errors">
          The format of your task name is invalid. {{ form.controls.taskName.errors.validateTaskName.reason }}
        </nz-form-explain>
      </nz-form-control>
    </nz-form-item>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5nhZ.png)
  constructor(private tasksService: TasksService,
              private fb: FormBuilder,
              private notificationService: NzNotificationService,
              private loggerService: LoggerService,
              private bsModalRef: NzModalRef,
              private router: Router) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      'taskName': this.taskName
    });`enter code here`

Comment: is `this.taskName` an Object ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not an example of a good question. A good question, requires a detailed description of the problem, coded examples of the current and previous attempts you have made, your current output and your desired output. Questions that are essentially, "Write my code for me." are not acceptable. See : [How to Ask A Good Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yes， this.taskName is  an Object

Comment: taskName = new FormControl('', validateTaskName);

  /**
   * Callback to parent which is called when task is created succesfully.
   */
  successCallback: () => void;

  constructor(private tasksService: TasksService,
              private fb: FormBuilder,
              private notificationService: NotificationService,
              private loggerService: LoggerService,
              private bsModalRef: BsModalRef) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      'taskName': this.taskName
    });
  }

Comment: the FormControl name  need to be a string set a string value for it

Comment: How to set string value

Comment: The problem is solved. Thank you very much.Another question is why the check code has not turned red.

Answer (score 4):

The issue has to do with how binding is implementend in Angular.

To pass static strings into a component one may use the following:

```
<app-component myProperty="value">
```

This will pass the string Value into the components myProperty member @Input.

To pass in the the value of an object however, one must use the [ ] brackets.

```
<app-component [myProperty]="obj">
```

This will bind the value of the object/ variable, etc. to the myProperty @Input.

With this in mind we will notice on line 28 that the reactive form property formControlName is set to the object taskName and not the string value (as the property expects) 'taskName'. Removing the brackets from the property will solve your issue.

```
   26     <input nz-input class="form-control input-sm"
   27        [id]="name"
   28        [name]="name" formControlName="taskName"
   29        type="text" placeholder="<Task Name>"/>
```

Further information may be found in the [Binding Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview)Angular documentation
and [FromControlName](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName)

Comment: The problem has been solved.Thank you very much. Another question is why the check code has not turned red.

Comment: Glad to help, I'm not sure what 'check code' you are talking about. I would guess that the type parser simply considers the component properties as objects rather than actually checking their defined type value.

Comment: The format of your task name is invalid. {{ form.controls.taskName.errors.validateTaskName.reason }}。This sentence will be turned red on the page, but not yet.

Comment: Ah the error message is not being displayed correctly. If you provide a minimal working example maybe someone will see the issue. At this point however I am unable to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice and help.

Comment: Thanks, stupidly had [formNameControl] instead of formNameControl in the HTML which was throwing this error